# Polymer 1.0 - How to use 'page' to route app and change URL

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, page.js

Working from the Polymer 1.0 Starter Kit, I'd like to set up a new route, but I need to fire it from a function in my app.js file rather than through routing.html

```
app._loadProject = function(e) {
  // do stuff here
  // after finished, route to our 'project' section in the app
  app.route = 'project';
};
```

This works for the most part. The application is routed to the 'project' `<section>`. However, the URL does not update to reflect this, so in cases where the user reloads the page, they find themselves on a different 'section' than the one they were just on - not the friendliest scenario.

Is there a more proper way to route with 'page' that doesn't break browser navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your thing in `app.js`:

```
app._loadProject = function(e) {
  // do stuff here
  // after finished, route to our 'project' section in the app
  page.show('/project'); // same as page('/project')
};
```

Add a rule in `routing.html`:

```
page('/project', project);
...
function project() {
  app.route = 'project';
}
```

Comment: This works and doesn't break the browser refresh button! I had the route set up in routing.html but didn't know how to properly trigger it. Thank you!